# Accessing a MooTools Class Method from outside the class

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a method inside of a MooTools class that I want to access after uploading a file with AJAX (iFrame).  The Javascript that the iFrame page runs when it loads should call the method of the Class, but I am unable to access it using anything like:
Class name: Main
var class was initialized in: myMain

parent.window.myMain.myMethod
parent.window.Main.myMethod

Is this even possible? If it is how do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax I prefer:

```
var MyClass = new Class({

  /* list regular non-static methods her as usual */

});

MyClass.staticMethod = function()
{
   /* body of static function */
};
```

The advantages you have are:

- You can call the static method via `MyClass.staticMethod()` inside and outside of your class
- It is not possible to accidentally access the this-pointer in the static method as it is not available

To access the static method in an inner frame use can `window.parent.MyClass.staticMethod();`

Comment: Is it possible to access from staticMethod to common methods defined in new Class(...)? i.e.: 
` MyClass.staticMethod = function(){ this.privateMethod()}; `

Comment: No, this isn't possible, see the second point of my answer. Static methods can only access other static methods. If you need to access `this` create a regular method.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (iframes too).

In main window.

```
var T=new MyClass();
```

In Iframe (which loads after T was initialized!)

```
window.parent.T.anyMethodOfMyClass()
```

Comment: I just keep getting "window.parent.myMain undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. On the iFrame page, I need to use:

window.parent.Main.prototype.myMethod();

Might not be the proper way of accessing it, but it works.